# DropDownList stuck after using .SelectedValue on him ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new with asp.net and i think this is really easy question, but i can't find the answer. I have a DropDownList on my page (that will be page A), one of the ways to go to that page is follow the link on the other page (page B). By this link i deliver some parameters, so i use them in the Page_load of page A:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strStatus = Request.QueryString["status"];
        DListStatus.SelectedValue = strStatus;
    }
```

But after it i couldn't choose something else exept this value, sometimes i saw that for a second new item is selected, but then in a blink of an eye it turns back to that preloaded one. I thought that .ClearSelection() will hepl, but it isn't (or maybe i use it in a wrong place). So i really wonder what to do and will really appreciate your help

Comment: Thank you for answers. Really a big relief for me. Thank's a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most important things you need to know about ASP.NET is the page life-cycle. There is plenty of help on the internet for this. Here is a quick link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/01/14/asp-net-page-life-cycle-diagram.aspx.

Notice that the `Page_Load` event is fire before any event handling. This means that if you are using an event handler to catch changes in the dropdown your current code will reset it to the query string value first.

Of course that is a very big problem so ASP.NET has added a `Page.IsPostBack` property to help. This will be true only one the first load of the page and false for all event handling postbacks. Using this information you can tweak your routine to only apply the value when `IsPostBack` is false.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    string strStatus = Request.QueryString["status"];
    DListStatus.SelectedValue = strStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if is it is a post back

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    string strStatus = Request.QueryString["status"];
    DListStatus.SelectedValue = strStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select a new item, does it invoke a post-back to the server?  Possibly for a `SelectedIndexChanged` event?

If so, you're clobbering the selected value on each post-back.  `Page_Load` gets invoked *a lot*.  Any time the page does anything server-side, basically.  It's part of the [page lifecycle](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/building-35-applications/page-lifecycle-events) for everything the page does.  So every event on the page (button click, selected index changed, etc.) is going to run the code in `Page_Load` before it runs any event handler code.

To avoid clobbering this value, you can wrap this code in a conditional to check if this is an initial page load vs. a triggered post-back:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string strStatus = Request.QueryString["status"];
        DListStatus.SelectedValue = strStatus;
    }
}
```